# Error:error:nomod Module Unavailable

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to load a module called ChapterCtrl but am not being able to because of the Module Unavailable error. Other modules are being loaded as expected. When running the site it causes the links to crash. However, on removing ChapterCtrl from the list of dependencies in the app module I've found that the site is working fine.

Here is the code for the ChapterCtrl.js file:

```
angular.module('ChapterCtrl', []).controller('ChapterController', function($scope) {});
```

Here is the app.js file:

```
angular.module('soulFront', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'MainCtrl', 'PageCtrl', 'PageService', 'ChapterCtrl', 'ChapterService']);
```

Here is the Page.js file for comparison:

```
angular.module('PageCtrl', []).controller('PageController', function($scope) {});
```

I've tried going through the Error Reference page but was unable to find any fix/solution to the issue. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks

**Edit**

Here is a snippet of the index.html file:

```
<!--CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!--JS-->
<script src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

<!--ANGULAR CUSTOM-->
<script src="js/controllers/MainCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/PageCtrl.js"></script>
<srcipt src="js/controllers/ChapterCtrl.js"></srcipt>
<script src="js/services/PageService.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/ChapterService.js"></script>
<script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, you probably forgot to add a `<script src="ChapterCtrl.js"></script>` in your html file.

Comment: Sorry about that, but if you look at the edited post, I've included a snippet of the index.html file for your convenience. Thanks

Comment: I apologize but I'm not sure what you meant by that

Comment: Read your index.html file. You're using `srcipt`instead of `script` to load your js file.

Comment: I see, sorry about that. Thanks